# Como ignorar archivos que están dentro de un rabol de carpetas?

Tags: git, vscode, github

gitignore no quiero que se actualice el contenido de un archivo .json, pero cuando lo agrego git sigue marcando como que fue modificado, más o menos este seria la ruta

```
src/c++/.vscode/c_cpp:properties.json
```

Estoy haciendo mal algo??

Comment: Probablemente ese archivo ya había aparecido en algún commit previo, por lo que no te lo ignorará aunque figure en el `.gitignore`. Para evitarlo (hacer que git deje de seguirle) debes hacer `git rm --cached src/c++/.vscode/c_cpp:properties.json` desde el raiz del repositorio

Comment: Cuando dices 'no quiero que se actualice', qué quieres decir exactamente? Quieres mantener una versión del archivo en la rama pero que no se guarden cambios adicionales? O no quieres guardar el archivo en la rama? Si no lo quieres tener en la rama, lo que comenta @abulafia es _lo mas sencillo_. Si quieres guardar el archivo pero sin que entren nuevas modificaciones, alguien acaba de hacer básicamente la misma pregunta durante el día.

Comment: Lo que quiero es que no se actualice en archivo, por que es uno en la que entaran algunos direcciones de carpetas y alguna que otra configuración muy especifica del desarrollador que se valla a engarcar luego de mi, simplemente quiero dejar una configuración basica y a traves del README.md diga como se debe configurar. espero se entienda